# property 'then' does not exist on type 'void' SVELTE

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch, svelte

So upon installing the latest version of Svelte for a new project I have the headache of having to adapt everything to use TypeScript or whatever this is that's policing every little thing I'm doing. I guess I prefer the loosely types approach.

So, In my components I want to call a simple function, such as

```
$gfunc.fetch('https://someotherplace',{
    testing:true
})
.then((ret)=>{

})
```

that pass the url and data to another function so I don't need to repeat myself

```
$gfunc.fetch = async (url,data)=>{
        let params
        if (data) {
            params = {
                method: 'POST', 
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            }
        } else {
            params = { method: 'GET' }
        }
        return fetch(url,params).then((ret)=>{
            //console.log('GOT RESPONSE SUCCESSFULLY',ret)
            const contentType = ret.headers.get("content-type");
            if (contentType && contentType.indexOf("application/json") !== -1) {
                return ret.json()
            } else {
                return ret
            }
        })
    }
```

Something here is causing the above error in the first component where the `then` is underlined red. Please advise, I'm new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to just remove the space between fetch and the parameters.

```
return fetch(url,params).then((ret)=>{
```

instead of

```
return fetch (url,params).then((ret)=>{
```

Having the space in between means that you are no longer calling a function but rather are calling the `then` method on `(url, params)`, which is void because it neither returns anything nor represents an object.

Comment: It shouldn't matter

Comment: I've made the edit, no change to the behaviour